# Confusion on Poker Hand concerning high card

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy

playing texas holem with some friends last night,  could tell me who wins this hand and why?

Player 1: 2, Q

player 2: 2, 3

TABLE: A, 2, 7, J, 4

Comment: This is the 3rd time you're posting a question that probably will end as a duplicate as well. Do you have problem understanding the _5 best cards rule_ question pointed to you?

Comment: For what seems like a daily need to repeat again and again: POKER HANDS HAVE FIVE CARDS, exactly five, no more, no fewer. Player 1's `2-2-A-Q-J` defeats Player 2's `2-2-A-J-7`.

Comment: Hey Doc, tell us exactly why this hand confuses you please. We might be able to better word a response so that you actually are able to read and understand a poker hand. What confuses you?